# Way to find if map contains any keys NOT from a list

Tags: dictionary, arraylist

I have a map and I'm trying to find out whether or not that map contains any keys OTHER THAN values provided in a list.

Something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("A", "A desctiption);
map.put("C", "C desctiption);
map.put("Z", "Z desctiption);
```

In this case I'd expect a TRUE returned as "Z" which is in the map doesn't belong to the list.

In the case the map was like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("B", "B desctiption);
map.put("C", "C desctiption);
```

I'd expect a FALSE returned as the map only contains items belonging to the list.

How can I achieve this?

*** UPDATE ***

I've tried with this but seems not to do the right job:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .anyMatch(entry -> !list.contains(entry.getKey()))
```

Comment: hi check out this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-containskey-method-in-java/

Comment: Thanks but the examples in that page are for the opposite I wanted to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ! on the list, why don't you try ..

```
boolean allKeysInList = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .allMatch(entry -> list.contains(entry.getKey()));
```

allKeysInList will be TRUE if all of the keys in the map are in the list and FALSE if not.

Comment: This works like a charm, I was approaching the problem the other way round but clearly I don't have a clear understanding of how the 'anyMatch()' method works